# which thing are necessary while uploading large size file php

Tags: php

I want to know that which thing are necessary while uploading large size (100mb and up) file in php. I have tried to increase **upload_max_filesize**. But which other thing are mandatory to upload securely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider following things while uploading large files

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');//You already mentioned
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 100);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);
```

Also check here : http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php